# instagram php scraping (gives error)

Tags: php, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I am pretty new to PHP so this may be a dumb question but yeah. I'm trying to get information about a user on instagram with this library: https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper
I've added the library and also the Unirest library so that it should work?

I also have this code in my index.php file:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Unirest/Exception.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Unirest/Method.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Unirest/Response.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Unirest/Request.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Unirest/Request/Body.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Instagram.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Endpoints.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Model/Account.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Model/Comment.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Model/Location.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Model/Media.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Model/Tag.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Exception/InstagramException.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Exception/InstagramAuthException.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/InstagramScraper/Exception/InstagramNotFoundException.php';
use InstagramScraper\Instagram;
$account = Instagram::getAccountById(272308256);
echo $account->username;

?>
```

But this code does not want to run :/. I keep getting this error:

```
 Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\Instagramposts\InstagramScraper\Instagram.php on line 313
```

I mean if it's a finished library it should immediately work? Anybody's got a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an instance of the class (object) first before using the method. The method makes use of the "this" operator which needs an object.
Your code should look like this:

```
use InstagramScraper\Instagram;
$insta = new Instagram;
$account = $insta->getAccountById(272308256);
echo $account->username;
```